# FlatCAM black plotting area problem

Tags: pcb-fabrication, software, gerber

I am trying to learn to use this software called FlatCAM that converts gerber files into gcode.

The problem is that my plotting area is completly black, and when I open the gerber files, I don't see anything:

[image]

What is going on?

It should look like this:

[image]

I am using version 8.993. I don't know if maybe it is a bug or maybe I need to press a button to activate it. Since I am new to this software, I don't know. Could someone with more experience help me?

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to change the mode from OpenGL to Legacy in the general settings.

[image]

Then press Applay and Save button